# Will the PrintWriter object will be garbage collected if we use flush() but not close() method in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, printwriter

In the following code, i'm sending message (broadcastMsg) to all list of socket connection specified in the clientSocketLister.

The PrintWriter object is initalized with autoFlush enabled !

My question is - Will the PrintWriter created in the for loop will be garbage collected even if there is no close() method to close the stream ?

Please, help !!

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)clientSocketLister.get(i);
    //PrintWriter with autoFlush enabled
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    writer.println(broadcastMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` object becomes eligible for GC when there are no more reachable references to it. Whether it has or hasn't called `close()` has nothing to do with it whatsoever.